# How to identify file that cannot be accessed

Tags: permissions

I'm running nethack-qt on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. (I believe in keeping both my operating system and my choice of games bang up-to-date. ;-) )

When I start up, I see the error

```
$ Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
```

The same thing happens with vanilla nethack, although obviously the message isn't visible until I exit the game.

Otherwise everything seems to work just fine. I can save and restore games, and the leaderboard seems to be ok.

Obviously I can work around the problem using `sudo`, but I'd rather just change the permissions on the file the game is trying, and failing to access. How would I go about tracking it down?

Comment: I don't know the program, so maybe it's a silly question, but could you clarify when the error appears? How are you running it? Like, could you call it with some verbose flag or something? (BTW, 12.04 is EOL and so we don't support it any more... but I don't think the OS version has anything to do with your problem, though I could be wrong as regularly happens)

Comment: The original game (nethack) runs from the command line and puts up some kind of alternative screen (like `less`) that obscures the terminal window, so I can only see the error message when I exit. There's a Qt port (nethack-qt) that puts up a brand new window and lets me see the terminal window it was started from. Running this, the error is displayed _very_ early, before the new window is displayed.

Comment: PS I'm aware that 12.04 LTS is dangerously long in the tooth - the reasons why I haven't upgraded might one day form the basis of another question.

Comment: You can check for unreadable files in your home dir with something like `find ~ -type f ! \( -user $USER -a -group $USER -a -perm -u+r \)`. For the record, "working around" permissions problems using `sudo` is probably the leading cause of. . . permission problems.

Comment: @steeldriver Executing your find command delivered an embarrassingly long list of files that I'm fairly confident are nothing to do with nethack. I'd like to try running under a different user, who probably has fewer/no unreadable files in their home dir, but am having trouble logging in or switching to another user; I appreciate that 12.04 LTS is unsupported so accept that I cannot run as any other user.

Comment: Well strictly speaking `-group $USER` should be `-group "$(id -gn)"`on the off chance that your primary group name and username are not the same. OTOH if you've made whole *directories* unreadable, then you may want to try with `find ~ -type d ! \( -user $USER -a -perm -u+x \)` first.

Comment: @steeldriver OK. First, I checked `id -gn` and it returns my username, so I'm going with the simpler command lines. The `find ... -type d ...` command returns some directories under `.teapot` which is Tcl-related; .mozilla/firefox and one directory under .cache/.mozilla/firefox which I'm confident are nothing to do with `nethack`. I tried to modify the `find ... -type f` command to exclude the two bigger directories in an attempt to seperate the wood from the trees, but couldn't manage to make it work (it still displayed files under those directories).

Comment: Try `find ~ \( -path '*teapot*' -o -path '*mozilla*' \) -prune -o -type f ! \( -user $USER -a -group $USER -a -perm -u+r \) -print` - place additional paths to be matched/pruned like `-o -path '*whatever*'` within the first bracket if necessary

Comment: @steeldriver Many thanks. After pruning out `*teapot*`, `*mozilla*`, `*git*` and three directories under Downloads - `Komodo-Edit*` (a Tcl editor), `emacs*` and `Image-ExifTool*` the remaining files under my home directory that are protected against me are `.rnd` (looks like a binary file, owned by `root`), three files under `.wireshark` that I always need to run using `sudo`, a file under `.config/libreoffice`, a file under `.emacs.d/auto-save-list`, one under `Downloads/mozjs-24.2.0` and koinstall.log, which I guess is the Komodo installation log. I honestly don't think any of these relevant

Comment: Yup. `koinstall.log` is a Komodo installation log.

Comment: Probably I'd try running the vanilla nethack under strace - (`strace nethack`) that should let you see exactly what file(s) it's trying to open. Regardless, IMHO there shouldn't really be *any* files in your home directory that are not owned by / readable by you.

Comment: Thanks for the `strace` advice. I'm having trouble interpreting the output, which I guess is a common reaction :-). I agree about not having any unreadable files in my home directory and am happy to have got rid of a good number of them. I knew even less about *nix when I set up this laptop than I do now, so I'm not surprised I've screwed up a few things. Thanks again for the patient advice.